# DDD. Should I modify a entity inside a repository?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories, repository-design

I have a question about implementing DDD and repository pattern.
Should I modify a entity inside a repository?

Let's say I have an Order and want to mark that order as finished.
As I see this I have two choices.

  1.

```
var order _orderRepository.GetById(1);
order.Finish();
_orderRepository.Update(order);
```

...where the change is persisted to the database in the *Update* call.

2.

```
var order _orderRepository.GetById(1);
var finishedOrder = _orderRepository.Finish(order);
```

...where the change is persisted to the database in the *Finish* call.

Is there a advantage of using one method over the other? What is the DDD-way of doing this?

Comment: The First one is the correct way.

Comment: @Jehof I think so too, but why should I prefer the first one over the other?

Comment: Cause I think that not the repository is responsible for marking an order as finished. Its up to a Command (when using CQRS) or a DomainService to do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not modify it in the repository.

The reason is that the repository is responsible of abstracting away the persistence (i.e. reading/writing to the data storage).

If you also make it responsible of some business logic you are violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

If you are doing automated testing, it also means that you have to do integration tests to be sure that the database communication/mapping works and then unit tests to verify the business logic that you introduced in it.

It can seem trivial. But it's only trivial the first time you violate the principle. But one violation usually leads to another and another and finally an application that isn't as easy to maintain :)

An application where classes have mixed responsibilities are also harder to navigate. Each time you want to update a feature you have to go through all layers to find where the actual logic is done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the application layer to coordinate behaviors for one or more domain objects, the domain objects should execute all state changes and lastly the repo should persist those changes to the database or wherever you are storing the domain's state.